# Dagger + ButterKnife = Could not initialize class dagger.internal.codegen.ModuleAdapterProcessor

Tags: android, dagger, butterknife

I have a project where I'm using ButterKnife for view injection, and I just added dagger but I'm getting the following error:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Internal compiler error:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   dagger.internal.codegen.ModuleAdapterProcessor at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   R.java  /Suggest/gen/com/google/android/gms line 0  Java Problem

I'm using eclipse and I have the following in my Annotation config:

[image]

notice: I have written one @module with its @provides ... correctly, then removed it and still I'm having the same compilation error

I followed this comment to setup Annotation processing:

https://github.com/square/dagger/issues/126#issuecomment-11992320

I'm not sure if it's code-related or dependency and versions related, I just need someone to point me to the possibilities behind this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those looking for a solution, I just found out that using JavaWriter 2.1.1 Fixed the problem